# Why isn't my property mapped to the entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, sonata-admin

i got a entity named Listing, here an overview of the table:

[image: describe listing table]

I tried to map the field "promoted" as the same as the field "certified", however this isn't working even if symfony tells me all is up-to-date with the db:

here's what i need to do with the "promoted" boolean field (same as "certified" field"), configure form fields:

```
$formMapper
            ->with('admin.listing.title')
            ->add(
                'status',
                ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'choices' => array_flip(Listing::$statusValues),
                    'placeholder' => 'admin.listing.status.label',
                    'translation_domain' => 'cocorico_listing',
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.status.label',
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'adminNotation',
                ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'choices' => array_combine(
                        range(0, 10, 0.5),
                        array_map(
                            function ($num) {
                                return number_format($num, 1);
                            },
                            range(0, 10, 0.5)
                        )
                    ),
                    'placeholder' => 'admin.listing.admin_notation.label',
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.admin_notation.label',
                    'required' => false,
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'certified',
                null,
                array(
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.certified.label',
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'promoted',
                null,
                array(
                    'label' => 'admin.listing.promoted.label',
                    'required' => false,
                )
            )
```

for the type of the certified it is "null" and it works, it find the type as a boolean, but for the promoted it does not find it i got this error:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Please define a type for field `promoted` in `Cocorico\ListingBundle\Admin\ListingAdmin`" at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/src/Builder/FormContractor.php line 69 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Please define a type for field `promoted` in `Cocorico\\ListingBundle\\Admin\\ListingAdmin` at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/src/Builder/FormContractor.php:69)"} []

[image]

here's my classe BaseListing.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Cocorico package.
 *
 * (c) Cocolabs SAS <contact@cocolabs.io>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model;

use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing;
use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Validator\Constraints as CocoricoAssert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Listing
 *
 * @CocoricoAssert\ListingConstraint()
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseListing
{

    /* Status */
    const STATUS_NEW = 1;
    const STATUS_PUBLISHED = 2;
    const STATUS_INVALIDATED = 3;
    const STATUS_SUSPENDED = 4;
    const STATUS_DELETED = 5;
    const STATUS_TO_VALIDATE = 6;

    public static $statusValues = array(
        self::STATUS_NEW => 'entity.listing.status.new',
        self::STATUS_PUBLISHED => 'entity.listing.status.published',
        self::STATUS_INVALIDATED => 'entity.listing.status.invalidated',
        self::STATUS_SUSPENDED => 'entity.listing.status.suspended',
        self::STATUS_DELETED => 'entity.listing.status.deleted',
        self::STATUS_TO_VALIDATE => 'entity.listing.status.to_validate',
    );

    public static $visibleStatus = array(
        self::STATUS_NEW,
        self::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
        self::STATUS_INVALIDATED,
        self::STATUS_SUSPENDED,
        self::STATUS_TO_VALIDATE,
    );


    /* Type */
    const TYPE_ONE = 1;
    const TYPE_TWO = 2;
    const TYPE_THREE = 3;

    public static $typeValues = array(
        self::TYPE_ONE => 'entity.listing.type.one',
        self::TYPE_TWO => 'entity.listing.type.two',
        self::TYPE_THREE => 'entity.listing.type.three',
    );

    /* Cancellation policy */
    const CANCELLATION_POLICY_FLEXIBLE = 1;
    const CANCELLATION_POLICY_STRICT = 2;

    public static $cancellationPolicyValues = array(
        self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_FLEXIBLE => 'entity.listing.cancellation_policy.flexible',
        self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_STRICT => 'entity.listing.cancellation_policy.strict',
    );

    public static $cancellationPolicyDescriptions = array(
        self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_FLEXIBLE => 'entity.listing.cancellation_policy_desc.flexible',
        self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_STRICT => 'entity.listing.cancellation_policy_desc.strict',
    );

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $status = self::STATUS_NEW;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=8, scale=0, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="assert.not_blank")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $price = 0;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="certified", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $certified;

    /**
     * @var boolean $promoted
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="promoted", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * 
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $promoted;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="min_duration", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $minDuration;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="max_duration", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $maxDuration;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cancellation_policy", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="assert.not_blank")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $cancellationPolicy = self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_FLEXIBLE;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="average_rating", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $averageRating;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment_count", type="integer", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $commentCount = 0;

    /**
     * Admin notation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="admin_notation", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=1, nullable=true)
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $adminNotation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="availabilities_updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $availabilitiesUpdatedAt;

    /**
     * Translation proxy
     *
     * @param $method
     * @param $arguments
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param  integer $status
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        if (!in_array($status, array_keys(self::$statusValues))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Invalid value for listing.status : %s.', $status)
            );
        }

        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Get Status Text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatusText()
    {
        return self::$statusValues[$this->getStatus()];
    }

    /**
     * Return available status for current status
     *
     * @param int $status
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getAvailableStatusValues($status)
    {
        $availableStatus = array(self::STATUS_DELETED);

        if ($status == self::STATUS_NEW) {
            $availableStatus[] = self::STATUS_PUBLISHED;
        } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_PUBLISHED) {
            $availableStatus[] = self::STATUS_SUSPENDED;
        } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_INVALIDATED) {
            $availableStatus[] = self::STATUS_TO_VALIDATE;
        } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_SUSPENDED) {
            $availableStatus[] = self::STATUS_PUBLISHED;
        }

        //Prepend current status to visible status
        array_unshift($availableStatus, $status);

        //Construct associative array with keys equals to status values and values to label of status
        $status = array_intersect_key(
            self::$statusValues,
            array_flip($availableStatus)
        );

        return $status;
    }


    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param  integer $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPriceDecimal()
    {
        return $this->price / 100;
    }

    /**
     * Get offerer amount fees
     *
     * @param array $feeAsOfferer
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAmountFeeAsOffererDecimal($feeAsOfferer)
    {
        return $this->getPriceDecimal() * $feeAsOfferer['percent'] + $feeAsOfferer['fixed'] / 100;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount to pay to offerer
     *
     * @param array $feeAsOfferer
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAmountToPayToOffererDecimal($feeAsOfferer)
    {
        return $this->getPriceDecimal() - $this->getAmountFeeAsOffererDecimal($feeAsOfferer);
    }

    /**
     * Get amount to pay to offerer minus VAT when listing price is VAT excluded.
     *
     * Return the same result than getAmountToPayToOffererDecimal used with listing price VAT is included:
     * amountToPayVATIncluded = PriceVATIncluded - (PriceVATIncluded * feeAsOfferer)
     * amountToPayVATExcluded = amountToPayVATIncluded / (1 + vatRate)
     *
     * So :
     * amountToPayVATIncluded = ((price * (1 + vatRate)) - (price * (1 + vatRate) * feeAsOfferer))
     * amountToPayVATExcluded = amountToPayVATIncluded / (1 + vatRate)
     * amountToPayVATExcluded = price - price * feeAsOfferer
     * amountToPayVATExcluded = getAmountToPayToOffererDecimal
     *
     *
     * @param array $feeAsOfferer
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function amountToPayToOffererForPriceExcludingVATDecimal($feeAsOfferer)
    {
        return $this->getAmountToPayToOffererDecimal($feeAsOfferer);
    }

    /**
     * Get offerer amount fees when listing price is VAT excluded.
     * Fees are computed on listing price VAT included
     *
     * @param array $feeAsOfferer
     * @param float $vatRate
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAmountFeeAsOffererForPriceExcludingVATDecimal($feeAsOfferer, $vatRate)
    {
        return $this->getAmountFeeAsOffererDecimal($feeAsOfferer) * (1 + $vatRate);
    }

    /**
     * Return the min listing price according to offerer fees and default min price.
     *
     * @param array $defaultFeeAsOfferer
     * @param int   $defaultMinPrice
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMinPrice($defaultFeeAsOfferer, $defaultMinPrice)
    {
        $result = $defaultMinPrice;
        /** @var  $this Listing */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if ($user) {
            $feeAsOfferer = $user->getFeeAsOfferer($defaultFeeAsOfferer);
            $result = max(round($feeAsOfferer['fixed'] / (1 - $feeAsOfferer['percent']), 2), $defaultMinPrice);
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @param array $defaultFeeAsOfferer
     * @param int   $defaultMinPrice
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMinPriceDecimal($defaultFeeAsOfferer, $defaultMinPrice)
    {
        return $this->getMinPrice($defaultFeeAsOfferer, $defaultMinPrice) / 100;
    }

    /**
     * Check if listing has correct min price according to offerer fees and default min price
     *
     * @param array $defaultFeeAsOfferer
     * @param int   $defaultMinPrice
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasMinPrice($defaultFeeAsOfferer, $defaultMinPrice)
    {
        if ($defaultMinPrice > 0 || $this->getPrice() > 0) {//if listing is not free or min price > 0
            $minPrice = $this->getMinPrice($defaultFeeAsOfferer, $defaultMinPrice);

            if ($this->getPrice() < $minPrice) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //else listing is free

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isCertified()
    {
        return $this->certified;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $certified
     */
    public function setCertified($certified)
    {
        $this->certified = $certified;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isPromoted()
    {
        return $this->promoted;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $promoted
     */
    public function setPromoted($promoted)
    {
        $this->promoted = $promoted;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param  integer $type
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        if (!in_array($type, array_keys(self::$typeValues))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Invalid value for listing.type : %s.', $type)
            );
        }

        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Type Text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTypeText()
    {
        return self::$typeValues[$this->getType()];
    }

    /**
     * Get certified
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCertified()
    {
        return $this->certified;
    }

    /**
     * Get promoted
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getPromoted()
    {
        return $this->promoted;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinDuration()
    {
        return $this->minDuration;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $minDuration
     */
    public function setMinDuration($minDuration)
    {
        $this->minDuration = $minDuration;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxDuration()
    {
        return $this->maxDuration;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $maxDuration
     */
    public function setMaxDuration($maxDuration)
    {
        $this->maxDuration = $maxDuration;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCancellationPolicy()
    {
        return $this->cancellationPolicy;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $cancellationPolicy
     *
     * @return BaseListing
     */
    public function setCancellationPolicy($cancellationPolicy)
    {
        if (!in_array($cancellationPolicy, array_keys(self::$cancellationPolicyValues))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Invalid value for listing.status : %s.', $cancellationPolicy)
            );
            //$cancellationPolicy = self::CANCELLATION_POLICY_FLEXIBLE;
        }

        $this->cancellationPolicy = $cancellationPolicy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Cancellation Policy Text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCancellationPolicyText()
    {
        return self::$cancellationPolicyValues[$this->getCancellationPolicy()];
    }

    /**
     * Get Cancellation Policy Description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCancellationPolicyDescription()
    {
        return self::$cancellationPolicyDescriptions[$this->getCancellationPolicy()];
    }

    /**
     * Set averageRating
     *
     * @param  integer $averageRating
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAverageRating($averageRating)
    {
        $this->averageRating = $averageRating;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get averageRating
     *1
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAverageRating()
    {
        return $this->averageRating;
    }

    /**
     * Set commentCount
     *
     * @param  integer $commentCount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCommentCount($commentCount)
    {
        $this->commentCount = $commentCount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commentCount
     *1
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCommentCount()
    {
        return $this->commentCount;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAdminNotation()
    {
        return $this->adminNotation;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $adminNotation
     */
    public function setAdminNotation($adminNotation)
    {
        $this->adminNotation = $adminNotation;
    }


    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getAvailabilitiesUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->availabilitiesUpdatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $availabilitiesUpdatedAt
     */
    public function setAvailabilitiesUpdatedAt($availabilitiesUpdatedAt)
    {
        $this->availabilitiesUpdatedAt = $availabilitiesUpdatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasPrice()
    {
        return $this->getPrice() > 0;
    }
}
```

Here's Entity\Listing.php:

```
<?php

namespace Cocorico\ListingBundle\Entity;

use Cocorico\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking;
use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\BaseListing;
use Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\ListingOptionInterface;
use Cocorico\ListingCategoryBundle\Entity\ListingListingCategory;
use Cocorico\ListingCharacteristicBundle\Entity\ListingListingCharacteristic;
use Cocorico\ListingDiscountBundle\Entity\ListingDiscount;
use Cocorico\ListingImageBundle\Entity\ListingImage;
use Cocorico\ListingLocationBundle\Entity\ListingLocation;
use Cocorico\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread;
use Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Listing
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cocorico\ListingBundle\Repository\ListingRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="listing",indexes={
 *    @ORM\Index(name="created_at_l_idx", columns={"created_at"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="status_l_idx", columns={"status"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="price_idx", columns={"price"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="type_idx", columns={"type"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="min_duration_idx", columns={"min_duration"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="max_duration_idx", columns={"max_duration"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="average_rating_idx", columns={"average_rating"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="admin_notation_idx", columns={"admin_notation"}),
 *    @ORM\Index(name="platform_notation_idx", columns={"platform_notation"}),
 *  })
 */
class Listing extends BaseListing
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable;
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    use \Cocorico\ListingSearchAdvancedBundle\Model\ListingSearchableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingCategoryFieldBundle\Model\ListingCategoryFieldableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\DeliveryBundle\Model\ListingDeliverableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingDepositBundle\Model\ListingDepositableTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingSessionBundle\Model\ListingSessionableTrait;

//    use \Cocorico\ServiceBundle\Model\ListingTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\ListingVideoBundle\Model\ListingVideoTrait;
//    use \Cocorico\CarrierBundle\Model\ListingCarrierableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Cocorico\CoreBundle\Model\CustomIdGenerator")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="assert.not_blank")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="listings", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingLocationBundle\Entity\ListingLocation", inversedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var ListingLocation
     **/
    protected $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingCategoryBundle\Entity\ListingListingCategory", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)//, fetch="EAGER"
     *
     */
    protected $listingListingCategories;

    /**
     * For Asserts @see \Cocorico\ListingBundle\Validator\Constraints\ListingValidator
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingImageBundle\Entity\ListingImage", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "asc"})
     */
    protected $images;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingCharacteristicBundle\Entity\ListingListingCharacteristic", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true) //, fetch="EAGER"
     *
     */
    protected $listingListingCharacteristics;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingDiscountBundle\Entity\ListingDiscount", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"fromQuantity" = "asc"})
     */
    protected $discounts;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "desc"})
     */
    protected $bookings;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "desc"})
     */
    protected $threads;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cocorico\ListingBundle\Model\ListingOptionInterface", mappedBy="listing", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $options;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->listingListingCategories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->discounts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->threads = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add characteristics
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCharacteristic(ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic)
    {
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics[] = $listingListingCharacteristic;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Remove characteristics
     *
     * @param ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     */
    public function removeListingListingCharacteristic(ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic)
    {
        $this->listingListingCharacteristics->removeElement($listingListingCharacteristic);
        $listingListingCharacteristic->setListing(null);
    }

    /**
     * Get characteristics
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|ListingListingCharacteristic[]
     */
    public function getListingListingCharacteristics()
    {
        return $this->listingListingCharacteristics;
    }

    /**
     * Get characteristics ordered by Group and Characteristic
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup()
    {
        $iterator = $this->listingListingCharacteristics->getIterator();
        $iterator->uasort(
            function ($a, $b) {
                /**
                 * @var ListingListingCharacteristic $a
                 * @var ListingListingCharacteristic $b
                 */
                $groupPosA = $a->getListingCharacteristic()->getListingCharacteristicGroup()->getPosition();
                $groupPosB = $b->getListingCharacteristic()->getListingCharacteristicGroup()->getPosition();

                $characteristicPosA = $a->getListingCharacteristic()->getPosition();
                $characteristicPosB = $b->getListingCharacteristic()->getPosition();
                if ($groupPosA == $groupPosB) {
                    if ($characteristicPosA == $characteristicPosB) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    return ($characteristicPosA < $characteristicPosB) ? -1 : 1;
                }

                return ($groupPosA < $groupPosB) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        );

        return new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
    }

    /**
     * Add characteristics
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup(
        ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
    ) {
        return $this->addListingListingCharacteristic($listingListingCharacteristic);
    }


    /**
     * Remove characteristics
     *
     * @param ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
     */
    public function removeListingListingCharacteristicsOrderedByGroup(
        ListingListingCharacteristic $listingListingCharacteristic
    ) {
        $this->removeListingListingCharacteristic($listingListingCharacteristic);
    }


    /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param  ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function addListingListingCategory(ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory)
    {
        $listingListingCategory->setListing($this);
        $this->listingListingCategories[] = $listingListingCategory;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory
     */
    public function removeListingListingCategory(ListingListingCategory $listingListingCategory)
    {
//        foreach ($listingListingCategory->getValues() as $value) {
//            $listingListingCategory->removeValue($value);
//        }

        $this->listingListingCategories->removeElement($listingListingCategory);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|ListingListingCategory[]
     */
    public function getListingListingCategories()
    {
        return $this->listingListingCategories;
    }


    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param  \Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Listing
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Cocorico\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

i have done the migration and validate schem, doctrine says it's all good:

[image]

However i can replace the 'null' for my field "promoted" by CheckBoxType::class, then i got no error and it looks like the certified:
[image]

But this is not working with the db, not persisiting the boolean in the db like Certified.. if someone know something that can help i'll be very happy, been stuck on this for a while..

EDIT: i found that BaseListing isn't included in the mapping such as BaseUser or BaseGroup:
[image]

This is maybe the cause, how could i include this please ?

Comment: ps: edited for more infos

Comment: `BaseListing` is not listed, because it's not an entity but a mapped super class. I also believe you're confusing form mapping with database/schema mapping. the only difference I notice is: your `$promoted` field has two `@var` annotations. in any case, you can just select a proper form element type instead of `null`, which I assume is one possible cause of your error.

Comment: @Jakumi i deleted the first var annotations and it's the same, and why i need to select a proper form element type because i dont need for the field Certified ?

Comment: actually, I don't know. I believe you (or someone with a surprisingly similar code) formerly also had a problem of similar fields being treated differently. being explicit helps sometime.

Comment: Yes it was me and i'm always on the same problem :/ but even if i choose a type like CheckBoxType, i dont have error but the field is not mapped with the property, i dont know why it dont persist the value to the db

Comment: oh btw, have you noticed the error message talks about `Cocorico\\ListingBundle\\Admin\\ListingAdmin` and thus NOT about just `...\\Listing`?

Comment: Yes i know, i told you this error was resolved like you said, by choosing a type for the field in the formMapper, but the field still is not mapped with the entity property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201262/discussion-between-jakumi-and-notmat).